# Chat - Unhide or unignore messages

Tags: support, chat

I just opened a chat with just one eye open today and misclicked somewhere. I think I have either "hide" the messages or "ignored" them by accident. How do I undo this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have ignored this user, you need to track the persons chat profile and "unignore" the user.

See this Q&A on Meta:
[How to unhide chat messages by hidden user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237072/how-to-unhide-chat-messages-by-hidden-user)

In case you have just "hidden" the messages, it just takes a refresh, since it is only enforced for a single session.

See this Q&A on Meta:
[In chat, what is the difference between "hide posts" and "ignore this user"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156160/in-chat-what-is-the-difference-between-hide-posts-and-ignore-this-user/156161#156161)

Comment: There's no need to track down the user's profile, just go to your own where you can see all of the accounts you have ignored.